# Running Github Action locally with vars context using nektos/act

Tags: github, github-actions, nektos-act

I'm trying to run a Github Action locally with nektos/act. I have Docker setup and everything works fine until I reference a Github variable (not a secret). Then I get the following error:

```
 Unable to interpolate expression 'format('{0}', vars.APP_ID)': Unavailable context: vars
```

How do I setup the `vars` context using a .env file?

```
on:
  pull_request:
  push:
jobs:
  build-test:
    name: Build & Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install Dependencies   
        run: npm ci
        working-directory: test/unit

      - name: Run Unit Tests
        run: npm run test:ci
        working-directory: test/unit

      - name: Install Integration Test Dependencies
        run: npm ci
        working-directory: test/integration

      - name: Run Integration Tests
        env:
          APP_ID: ${{ vars.APP_ID }}

      #...omitted
```

Comment: could be related? https://github.com/nektos/act/issues/1558

Comment: Wouldn't it be an option to use an `env file` instead of `vars`? As specified [here](https://github.com/nektos/act#configuration)? And then just call it by using `${{ env.APP_ID }}` ?

Comment: @Matteo Yes, definitely related.

Comment: @GuiFalourd It might be an option, but how would I use both an env file and secrets together?

Comment: You can configure the secret file separately as well as stated in the [act readme file](https://github.com/nektos/act#secrets).

Comment: @Matteo @GuiFalourd I have this working now based on your comments. So #1, it appears `vars` context isn't supported with act, and #2 the secrets file can be used locally. So one of you can answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not an option. The [listed issue on github](https://github.com/nektos/act/issues/1558) addresses it - i don't see how `act` is ready for prime-time without this!

The workaround is to *change your workflow file* to use `env.` instead of `vars.`, and change it back when you are ready to push it up to github. This is not a good workaround! But it's the best anyone seems to be able to offer.

Comment: Or just not use the vars context at all, which is what I ended up doing.

Comment: I get it, but I only have Secrets and Variables available in my repo; Environment isn't an option AFAIK unless I'm not understanding something (which is always highly likely).

Comment: You just have to write directly to ‘$GITHUB_ENV’ as described here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to use the var file by providing the `--var-file` argument [see docs](https://nektosact.com/beginner/index.html#vars).
For example `act -j build-test .github/workflows/workflow.yml --var-file .vars`

```ini
# .vars
APP_ID=123456
```